# how to get nested relationship in the view

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

some fields return an empty result

here category_set is empty but I have a category

for this what i have tried is here

**models.py**

```
   class Category(models.Model):
        category = models.CharField(max_length=128)
        profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.category


class Interest(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=250, default='')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**serializers.py**

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    interest_set = InterestSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
      model = Category
      fields = ['id', 'category', 'interest_set']


class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category_set = CategorySerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
      model = Profile
      fields = []
```

How can I get right content? any help?

Comment: The `fields = []` are empty?

Comment: No. I just did not entered whole fileds value. It has values as image shows above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it with SerializerMethodField

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework.serializers import SerializerMethodField 

class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    interest_set = InterestSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('id', 'category', 'interest_set')

class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category_set = SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('***your Fileds** include category_set here',)

    def get_category_set(self, obj):
        cats_qs = Category.objects.filter(profile_id=obj.id) ##QuerySet
        serialized = CategorySerializer(cats_qs, many = True)
        return serialized.data
```

Comment: can you tell me please? in this solution it works for only category_set but if i want to add another field can I do this with ModelNameSerilizer()? I mean how to combine this? Thank you

Comment: Yes. You can use it for any fields. x=SerializerMethodField().  def get_x(self, obj):  here is obj your Meta.model instance.

Comment: And it's works faster than another nested serializer fields.

Comment: yes I see) but why did not it work with nested serializer? but another one worked as you see in the pics